# How to figure out a 615 digits long decryption key given these RSA properties?

Tags: cryptography

I have

- a public key $(n,e)$ where modulus $n$ has 615 decimal digits.
- a decryption exponent $d$ with 8 decimal digits currupted with known positions.
- a plaintext-ciphertext pair $c_1 = m_1^e \bmod n$
- just a ciphertext c_2 encrypted with the public key $(n,e)$

I want to decrypt $c_2$.

---

I'm sorta lost on what I can do with these information. My main focus is trying to get D1. It is 615 char. long, with 8 digits randomly missing throughout it. Trying to bruteforce it would be going through 10$^8$ possibilities. Even if I can somehow do that, what would I even do with all of them? decrypt the ciphertext and see which D1 matches the plaintext? I dont know if that possible on a laptop.

I tried computing the euler phi function of N, but being a large number, I dont know if i can compute it. I had it running for 20min before I interrupted the calculation.

What else can I do with all this information?

Thank you

Comment: $10^8 \approx 2^{27}$ that is quite easy to reach with a laptop. With a ciphertext-plaintext pair, you can test each for $d_1$.

Comment: @kelalaka what would I use to/how would I compute them?

Comment: @kelalaka its like "1242x246235x623523..." where each x is a missing number, and the entire value is 615 char long. Sorry if i am unclear

Comment: @kelalaka I do know the location of the missing digits

Comment: @kelalaka im sorry, I do not quite understand. I have both a plaintext-ciphertext pair, and also a ciphertext which I want to decrypt. $d$ is a number which is 615 characters long and is missing 8 digits. Which part am I failing to explain?

Comment: @kelalaka sorry, I did not mean character as in that. I meant that $d$ is 615 char long. For e.g. the number 1527 is 4 char. long. So $d$ is 615 char long in the same way. And yes, they are all digits.

Comment: Then for each missing digit, apply brute force; construct the candidate $d$  and decrypt ciphertext to see that it matches its corresponding plaintext. Once the key is found, decrypt the ciphertext to obtain its plaintext.

Comment: My, last comment is your way, calculation phi is hard.

Answer (score 1):

**Brute-Force**

The easiest way is the brute-force the corrupted digits on $d$. Since you have 8-digit corrupted with known positions iteration on them will cost $10^8 \approx 2^{27}$ which is quite easily accessible today home computers. What supercomputer can reach please see [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/63537/18298) post from Cryptography.

Once you determined the correct value of the missing digit, you can decrypt the given ciphertext.

**Calculating the $\varphi(n)$ form $(n,e)$**

If you were able to calculate the $\varphi(n)$ easily, there will be a problem for RSA;

Assume that there is an Oracle $O$ that given $n$ outputs $\varphi(n)$. Since the attacker knows the public key $(n,e)$ then he will ask the $O$ for $\varphi(n)$. Once the $O$ outputs the $\varphi(n)$ then by using the relation $$e \cdot d \equiv 1 \pmod \varphi(n)$$ the attacker will be able to find the private exponent $d$. Therefore, an efficient way to find the $\varphi(n)$ without factoring is equal to breaking RSA.